# Static Cache on Android / Mobile Device for Efficiency

Tags: java, android, performance

What is the best way to maintain a static cache on an Android device?

For example, say I have the look-up tables `Type` and `Category` - these two tables will rarely change....but if they do, they must be refreshed.

How can I store this data in some sort of cache on an Android device, while still updating them when something changes on the **server?** Seeing as they rarely change, I would like to **minimize** the amount of data being sent/received from the device.

**Note** - there are more look-up tables than this, I am just using two as an example.

Answer (score -1):

Create A singleton instance of static HashTable/HashMap and store objects which contains data to populate screens ( Like primitive, pojo ,collections ect ) and a flag as well which will notify whether that value is being refreshed . set this value when you read any change from server . update with fresh value  .

Comment: `HashTable` is already synchronized.  If you are using either that or a synchronized wrapper around `HashMap` then unless you need _exclusive_ access to the map then `ConcurrentHashMap` is better.  Here's a performance graph for example: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/concurrenthashmap_scalability.shtml